# ruby missing psych/versions

Tags: ruby, gitlab, fedora, psych

I upgrade fedora from 25 to 26, and then ruby(2.4.1) have an error with psych.

```
usr/share/ruby/yaml.rb:5:in `<main>': It seems your ruby installation
is missing psych (for YAML output). To eliminate this warning, please
install libyaml and reinstall your ruby. rake aborted! LoadError:
cannot load such file -- psych/versions
```

But I can import `psych/versions` in `irb`.

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'psych/versions'
=> true
irb(main):003:0>
```

I have tried to reinstall ruby but the problem is as well.

I run the same code in `yaml.rb` near line 5 with irb. Nothing is wrong.

The question is on gitlab after I update my system. So I suppose the code is right and the reason is in myself.

Comment: The upgrade may have changed the system load path for ruby gems. This happens sometimes with Linux. Your irb can still find the gems but gitlab may not be able to.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Alright, I find a pull request for gitlab about the question.. The reason is about Gemfile.